# Updating sQL Server from datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have searched for this solution and found answers quite close but not able to resolve what I need. I have a form that populates a datagridview with data from an Access table. Once populated, I need to then append that information to a table in sql server. What is best way to do this please? thanks for any help

here is my code;

```
    'connect to access

    Dim myDBconn As New OleDbConnection("connection details here")

    ' SQL Statement  

    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomerUpdates"

    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myDBconn)

    ' Gets the records from Access table and fills  adapter

    Dim dt1 As New DataTable("CustomerDetails")

    adapter.Fill(dt1)

    Dim sql1 As String

    sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomerDetails"

    Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, myDBconn)

    Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(sql1, myDBconn)

    myDBconn.Open()

    Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader

    myreader.Read()

    ' DataSource for the DataGridView  

    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt1

    'now need to grab data from the datagridview or adapter and append rows to a table in sql server?
```

Answer (score 0):

Question on my end: What's the code after `adapter1.Fill(dt1)` supposed to do? It does the same select again and only reads the first result from the select - then it does nothing with it?

Apart from that:

After `adapter.Fill(dt1)` you have a data table. What you want to do now is:

1. Create a `SqlConnection` to your SQL server
2. Create a `SqlDataAdapter` named `sqlAdapter` with a proper `INSERT` statement
3. Use `sqlAdapter.Update(dt1)` to insert the rows from your table into the database

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much for your answer. I think I was looking at different options with that 2nd bit of code. I am finding it quite complex - there seems to me lots of ways of achieving this. I have managed to get it working as follow but I will have to create 24 fields of data with the command.parameter method. If there is an easier way, please let me know. thanks

Dim conn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

```
    conn.ConnectionString = "conn string"

    command.CommandText = "insert into tblCustomerprocessing (custTitleID,custInits,custSurname,custAdd1) values (@title,@initials,@surname,@custadd1)"

    command.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.Int)
    command.Parameters.Add("@initials", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    command.Parameters.Add("@custadd1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)

    conn.Open()

    command.Connection = conn

    'load grid

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2

        command.Parameters(0).Value = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        command.Parameters(1).Value = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        command.Parameters(2).Value = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        command.Parameters(3).Value = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next

    conn.Close()
```